# Dart/Flutter convert from String to String?

Tags: flutter, dart

Ive been learning flutter, and have been taught to make classes like so

```dart
class PlayerCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Players profile1;
  final Function delete;

  PlayerCard({this.profile1, this.delete});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.grey[600],
      elevation: 30.0,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(profile1.name 'Sorry, weve hit a problem', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),),
            Text(profile1.age 'Sorry, weve hit a problem'),
            Center(child: TextButton.icon(onPressed: delete, icon: Icon(Icons.delete), label: Text("Delete"),))
          ],
        ),
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 5.0, 15.0, 5.0),
    );
  }
}
```

but, (maybe due to a new version of dart/flutter), it forces me to have my variables "nullable" like so,

```dart
class PlayerCard extends StatelessWidget {
  final Players? profile1;
  final Function? delete;

  PlayerCard({this.profile1, this.delete});

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Card(
      color: Colors.grey[600],
      elevation: 30.0,
      child: Padding(
        padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
        child: Column(
         crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
          children: <Widget>[
            Text(profile1?.name?? 'Sorry, weve hit a problem', style: TextStyle(fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 20.0),),
            Text(profile1?.age?? 'Sorry, weve hit a problem'),
            Center(child: TextButton.icon(onPressed: delete, icon: Icon(Icons.delete), label: Text("Delete"),))
          ],
        ),
      ),
      margin: EdgeInsets.fromLTRB(15.0, 5.0, 15.0, 5.0),
    );
  }
}
```

i found out how to convert the String variables that are passed through the class into a String? (`profile1?.name?? 'Sorry, weve hit a problem'`) but when i try call a function that is passed through the class, i cannot because "The argument type 'Function? cant be assigned to parameter type void Function()?'" which i assume has something to do with with converting it to be nullable.

I tried having a look for similiar situations and answers but nothing

Comment: Can you please check in `Players` model if name and age are nullable or not.
I think these members are defined as null, because flutter doesn't show this kind of error.

Comment: Just change `final Function? delete;` to `final void Function()? delete;`

Comment: `T` is a subtype of `T?`.  No explicit conversion is necessary.  Your problem is that `Function` means *any* function with any return type and with any arguments, and that's not a subtype of `void Function()` which is required to take no arguments.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> but, (maybe due to a new version of dart/flutter), it forces me to have my variables "nullable" like so,

If you want to make them non-nullable, you need to fix the constructor.

You can either make them `required`:

```dart
PlayerCard({required this.profile1, required this.delete});
```

Or provide default values:

```dart
PlayerCard({this.profile1 = <const Players object>, this.delete = <const Function()>});
```

In your case I understand that you want to make them required (and also I do not think you can make a constant function).

---

> "The argument type 'Function? cant be assigned to parameter type void Function()?'"

About this, the error is telling your that you are trying to pass a `void Function()?` for a field that is `Function?` typed. The problem here is with your declaration of `delete`:

```dart
final void Function()? delete;
```

(If you make it required in the constructor you can remove `?` here too).